# Firebass App Disitrbution upload apk with gradle

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-app-bundle, firebase-app-distribution

My app consists of two dynamic modules and instant app. I'm using **app bundle** to upload my production builds to the Play Store.
When I'm trying to upload apk to the **Firebase App Distribution**, I use command:

```
./gradlew assembleVariantRelease appDistributionUploadVariantRelease
```

Unfortunately, app uploaded in this way results in a crash, and the stacktrace tells me that there are some classes from dynamic modules, that are missing.

The solution I found was to use **bundletool** and extract **universal.apk** from it. It turns out, the apk extracted works great, has all the classes included for the app to work.

When I was using **Fabric Beta** to distribute app, I just needed to provide apk to `/projectPath/app/build/outputs/apk/variant/release` and run `./gradlew crashlyticsUploadDistributionVariantRelease` for it to work. It uploaded working apk file as expected.

When I tried to do the same with Firebase App Distribution (providing the universal apk to the right folder then running `./gradlew appDistributionUploadVariantRelease` without adding `assembleVariantRelease` first), it seems that the command not only uploads apk to the Firebase, but also overwrites my previous apk file by building a new one.

When I upload universal.apk to Firebase manually (via web console), it also works fine.

My question is: Is there a gradle command for Firebase App Distribution to only upload apk from specific folder without triggering a build of a new apk file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was just working on this, current firebase documentation is not improved yet so I decided to move to CLI, where you can point out apk path. In midway through, my friend asked about this in firebase-community slack and turns out you can point out apk by adding `apkPath` to app distribtuion block in gradle.

P.S.: You can join community slack from here -> https://firebase.community/

Comment: Thank you, looks like this is the answer